# Enable routes based on container parameters in Symfony 2.3

Tags: symfony

I created a bundle which has its own routing.yml. 
Instead of simply importing those routes in my application's main routing.yml, I would like to import them only if a certain parameter is set in the service container. 
This way I could enable or disable routes based on the bundle configuration. Is there any way to do this except by creating a new environment?

The reason I want to do this is because I need some routes for a special stress-testing setup which should never be enabled in other deployments.

Comment: please explain why do you need to enable/disable some routing rules?

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically create routes by creating your own [Route Loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html)

First, declare the service

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    acme_foo.route_loader:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\Loader\MyLoader
        arguments:
            - %my.parameter%
        tags:
            - { name: routing.loader }
```

Then, create the class

<kbd>**Acme\FooBundle\Loader\MyLoader**</kbd>

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\Loader;

class MyLoader extends Loader
{
    protected $params;

    public function __construct($params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function supports($resource, $type = null)
    {
        return $type === 'custom' && $this->param == 'YourLogic';
    }

    public function load($resource, $type = null)
    {
        // This method will only be called if it suits the parameters
        $routes   = new RouteCollection;
        $resource = '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/config/custom_routing.yml';
        $type     = 'yaml';

        $routes->addCollection($this->import($resource, $type));

        return $routes;
    }
}
```

Then just add the importation into your routing

<kbd>**app/config/routing.yml**</kbd>

```
_custom_routes:
    resource: .
    type:     custom
```

Comment: This is in the cookbook, and I tried this. It seems something is missing though, because the Loader doesn't have a Resolver.

Comment: What do you mean by *"doesn't have a Resolver"* ? The [`LoaderResolver`](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/LoaderResolver.html) always [set itself](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/LoaderResolver.php#L69) as a resolver when adding a loader.