# Is it possible to add custom routes during compilation passes?

Tags: symfony, bundle, router

I prepare external bundle and I would like to add some routes during compilation passes. 
Routes will be created on the main `app/config/config.yml` settings.

I was trying to get `router` from `ContainerBuilder` in my `CustomCompilerPass` via:

```
$definition = $container->getDefinition('router');
```

, but I got `The service definition "router" does not exist`.

Is it possible to add custom routes during compilation passes?

Comment: `router` is an alias of `router.default`, maybe using this instead would do. But, why would you add routes at compiler time ? Is there anything wrong using a [custom loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html) ?

Comment: You cant add anything during compilation passes. You can only get service definitions, its not the same as then you access it in controller with `$container->get()`

Comment: @forgottenbas that's nosense. You can get everything you can get from `ContainerBuilder`, which means you get access to more than the container...

Comment: @Touki I used your advice (did custom loader) it works great. Please post your comment as answer to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to add routes at compiler passes.
In order to dynamicly load routes (aware of container parameters) I'd use a [custom route loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html) as given in my [previous example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18506571/1607098)

```
class MyLoader extends Loader
{
    protected $params;

    public function __construct($params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function supports($resource, $type = null)
    {
        return $type === 'custom' && $this->params == 'YourLogic';
    }

    public function load($resource, $type = null)
    {
        // This method will only be called if it suits the parameters
        $routes   = new RouteCollection;
        $resource = '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/config/dynamic_routing.yml';
        $type     = 'yaml';

        $routes->addCollection($this->import($resource, $type));

        return $routes;
    }
}
```

<kbd>**routing.yml**</kbd>

```
_custom_routes:
    resource: .
    type:     custom
```

Answer (score 0):

`router` is an alias, not a service. To get that from a `ContainerBuilder`, use `ContainerBuilder::getAlias`. To get the service ID, you need to cast that object to a string: `(string) $container->getAlias('router')`. Now, you can use that ID to get the service: `$container->getDefinition($container->getAlias('router'))`. And then you get the Service which you can modify to add routes.

---

BTW, I'm not sure if this is really the thing you want. What about using the [CmfRoutingBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/routing.html). Then, you use the Chain Router, so you can use both the Symfony2 router and the DynamicRouter. The DynamicRouter can be used with a custom route provider, in which you return the routes you want (you can get them from every resource you want).

Comment: Thanks! Now I got `router` definition, but I don't know how can I add custom route? I noticed that I should add `Route` to `RouteCollection` . Can I do that in compilation passes?

Comment: @Wouter J, also want to know it. How could you achieve this with only definition of service?

Comment: hmm, it turns out you can't. I really think the best option is to use the CmfRoutingBundle

Comment: @WouterJ Unfortunately I have sf 2.1 version so I cannot use RoutingBundle. I did custom loader, it works great.